# javascript re-define a variable

Tags: javascript

I'm getting stuck somewhere (as newbies do). Is it ok to re-define a variable once it has been trimmed and tested for content?

```
    function setarea() {

        var dbasedata = document.forms[0]._dbase_name.value;
            dbasedata = dbasedata.toUpperCase();
            dbasedata = dbasedata.replace(/\s/g, "");
            dbasedata = dbasedata.remove("UK_CONTACTS", "");

        if (dbasedata != "") {
            _area.value = _dbase_name.value;
        } 

   else var dbasedata = document.forms[0]._dbase_name.value;
            dbasedata = dbasedata.toUpperCase();
            dbasedata = dbasedata.replace(/\s/g, "");

        if (dbasedata.indexOf("UK_CONTACTS")>-1 {
        var dbaseterm = "UK_CONTACTS";
   else var dbaseterm = "";     
            }
```

Comment: Your identation doesn't really help with reading your code :).

Comment: Have a look at [this hoisting article](http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/2/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting), it may explain a few related concepts.

Comment: better do: var dbaseterm = (dbasedata.indexOf("UK_CONTACTS") > -1)?'UK_CONTACTS':'';

Comment: A little off topic, but I'd chain those first lines in the function. `var dbasedata = document.forms[0]._dbase_name.value.toUpperCase().replace(/\s/g, "").remove("UK_CONTACTS", "");` I assume `.remove()` is being added to `String.prototype`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may 'work', but isn't recommended.  You don't need to redeclare it.

Probably want to run your code through [JSLint](http://jslint.com) .  There are a few tidyness/bracing issues you would want to address.

Answer (score 4):

It makes no sense to use `var` more than once for the same variable in the same scope. Since all `var x;` are hoisted to the top of the scope every additional `var` on that variable will be a no-op.

Assigning a new value is fine though - they are variables and not constants after all.

```
function x() {
    var x = 123;
    foo();
    x = 456;
    var y = 'hello';
    var x = 678;
}
```

is actually this internally:

```
function x() {
    var x, y; // both are === undefined
    x = 123;
    foo();
    x = 456;
    y = 'hello';
    x = 678;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this and it is legal.

Comment: It is legal but the 'var' declaration is not needed after line: '  dbasedata = dbasedata.remove("UK_CONTACTS", "");'

Comment: I want to test the string to see if it contains UK_CONTACTS. If it does I want it to do something. Then, I want to test the the same original string after removing UK_CONTACTS (and white spaces) to see if there is anything else in the string. Not sure how to do that without re-defining the string again.